# unable to load Private Key using random hex generated passkey openssl

Tags: bash, macos, openssl, rsa

I'm writing a bash script to generate and use a RSA private key. When I run it, it can't generate a private key and says "unable to load Priavate Key" then :Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY.

It works when I run the genrsa commands through iTerm2 using pass:foo as a passphrase but I can't get it to use the hex string I generate in the gen_hex function.

```
gen_hex() {
    # generate random hexadecimal string/array
    echo hexdump -n 16 -e '4/4 "%08X" 1 "\n"' /dev/random
}

check_for_keys() {
    if [ ! -f ./public.pem ]; then
        echo "> Generating Passphrase..."
        passp = $(gen_hex)

        touch pass.txt
        echo $passp > pass.txt
        echo "> Done."

        echo "> Generating keys..."
        openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:$passp -out private.pem 4096
        echo "> Done."

        echo "> Exporting Public Key..."
        openssl rsa -in private.pem -passin pass:$passp -outform PEM - 
        pubout - out public.pem
        echo "> Done."

    fi
}
```

Full error message:

```
:unable to load Private Key 35508:error:0906D06C:PEM 
routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line: 
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098- 
64.50.6/src/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:648:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have (at least) two significant problems. First, `gen_hex` doesn't produce a hexadecimal string; it outputs the command you want to run. Drop the `echo`. Second, you cannot put spaces around the `=` in an assignment.

```
gen_hex() {
  # generate random hexadecimal string/array
  hexdump -n 16 -e '4/4 "%08X" 1 "\n"' /dev/random
}
```

and

```
passp=$(gen_hex)
```

Third, you should quote `$passp` wherever it is used to avoid any nasty surprises involving shell interpretation of any of the characters in the string. To be safe, I would use `printf` instead of `echo` as well, if for no other reason than to avoid the newline that `echo` will append to the end of the passphrase.

```
printf '%s' "$passp" > pass.txt
```